# Doubt about best move in lichess.org training puzzle

Tags: puzzles, lichess

In this puzzle, https://lichess.org/training/61639, in this position:

```
1k2n1rr/1b4q1/1p1p1p2/1PpPpQ2/2P1PnN1/2N4P/R5PK/R2B4 b - - 10 33
```

the engine says that the best move for black is Rh5, I think it should be Bc8.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Can you explain why you think Bc8 is better than Rh5 [I think you mistyped that one]?

Comment: I am sorry for my silly moves, @Annatar I think I can learn a lot in this forum

Comment: No need to be sorry, noone ever stops learning in chess. ;)

Comment: The engine tells you why it's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. After ...Bc8??, Ra8+ checks win for white.